# Overflowing Child Element

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, resize

The div element with class `main-game` is overflowing. The element is resizing based on the `<p>` tag with class `title`. But, I want it the other way round.

[Image with problem for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxyzJ.png)

```
<div id="game">
    <div class="main-game">
        <p class="title">Play Game</p>
        <div class="head">
            <div class="num-box" id="box"><p class="num" id="number" name="number">?</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <p>Enter a number:</p>
            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="input" id="">
            <p id="status"></p>
        </div>
        <button id="submit" onclick="checkNumber()" class="green submit-num">submit</button>
        <button id="refresh-btn" hidden onclick="reloadPage()" class="yellow submit-num refresh">play again</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#game {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
}
.main-game {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.main-game .title {
    font-size: 42px;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit this to use [Stacked Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to get minimal repeatable demo?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can use a combination of align-self and max-content on the .main-game class. Here's how you can modify your CSS:

```
#game {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
}

.main-game {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: start; /* Align the div to the start of the flex container */
    width: max-content; /* Set the width to the width of its content */
    margin: auto; /* Center the div horizontally within the flex container */
}

.main-game .title {
    font-size: 42px;
    width: fit-content;
}
```